# c++ covariant constructions with respect to template parameters

Tags: c++, inheritance

I have a base class and its derived class with pointers to forward declared classes:

```cpp
class BaseParam;

template <class S = BaseParam> class Base;

class BaseParam {
private:
    std::unique_ptr<Base<>> ptr;
public:
    virtual const Base<>& get_ptr() const {return *ptr;}
};
```

And similarly for its derived class

```cpp
class DerivedParam;

template <class S = DerivedParam> class Derived;

class DerivedParam : public BaseParam {
private:
    std::unique_ptr<Derived<>> ptr;
public:
     const Derived<>& get_ptr() const override {return *ptr;}  // <---- Here we'll have trouble
};
```

The above mentioned class templates are also intertwined with the `Param` versions, here's the prototype:

```cpp
template <class S>
class Base {
private:
    std::unique_ptr<S> ptr;
    // ...
public:
    // ...
    const S& get_ptr() const { return *ptr; }
};

template <class S>
class Derived : public Base<S> {
};
```

So that `Derived = Derived<DerivedParam>` inherits from `Base<DerivedParam>` But in order to make the return marked with `<--` above covariant, we would need `Derived` to inherit from `Base = Base<BaseParam>`. How does one do this in a clean fashion? I cannot add an extra inheritance say like

```
template <class S>
class Derived: public Base<S>, public virtual Base<>
```

Cause `Base` and `Base<DerivedParam>` will hold two different pointers to `BaseParam` and to `DerivedParam`. Since a pointer to `DerivedParam` decays to one to `BaseParam` there should be a solution where the base class holds only one pointer.

So what I am asking is if there is some functorial way of defining class inheritance for class templates.

Comment: From just the sample posted you're already failing at
        std::unique_ptr<Base> ptr;
since Base is missing a type param

Comment: Base has a defaulted template parameter. Anyway I think the simplest solution is to have both `Base` and `Derived` inheriting from an abstract base class with all the methods from base being pure virtual and just storing pointers to this abstract class

Comment: Even with default, it would be `std::unique_ptr<Base<>> ptr;`...

Comment: Right, in my application I had plenty of extra parameters, didn't copy it right :)

Comment: Maybe do something like `template <class S> class Derived : public Base<typename S::parent> {};`

Comment: It is an interesting question in its own right. However, I do wonder why a `FooParam` class needs to have an owning pointer back to `Foo`? What concrete problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @G.Sliepen Yeah I can't really solve it even with an abstract class that all depend. `Base` and `Derived` model mathematical objects. An instance of Derived is an object of `Base` with extra structure. `DerivedParam` and `BaseParam` model the elements of the respective mathematical objects (think as vectors in a vector space). Base needs to hold pointers to some of its objects (like the zero vector, unit vector and so on), and each element needs to hold pointers to their parent.

Comment: @Jarod42 that's an interesting idea and I think it would solve the covariant call, but the problem is that `Derived` does need to inherit from `Base<DerivedParam>` since most of the methods in `Base<S>` are really dependent on `S`.

Comment: *"intertwined"* seems an apropos description of the situation. I'd be inclined to look at the relationships for a bit (to get a better understanding of them), then kick this back to the class-design stage. See if appropriate levels of abstraction have been utilized.